# Array in C# with data of XML

Tags: c#, xml

I get a XML and I want to get the value of Role to make an array in C#, and then remove the same value to make another one.xml goes here:

```
<Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
<Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
<Phrase  Role="1"></Phrase>
<Phrase  Role="1"></Phrase>
<Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
<Phrase  Role="1"></Phrase>
<Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
```

Here is my start up, I get all the Role, but when I add them in to an array it doesn't show the value of the Role, just get System.Int32[]. 
The load xml and transform to class code goes here:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="1"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="1"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="1"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>");
    //get all the phrases
        XmlNodeList phrases = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Phrase");
            foreach (XmlNode phraseNode in phrases)
            {
                Phrase phrase = NodeToPhrase(phraseNode);
                phrasesList.Add(phrase);
            }
    //Phrase node to phrase
        private Phrase NodeToPhrase(XmlNode node)
        {
            Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
            XmlNode roleNode = node.Attributes["Role"];
            if (roleNode != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleNode.Value))
                phrase.Role = roleNode.Value;

            return phrase;
        }   
//Crate a phrase class
public Dictionary<string, Phrase> Phrases = new Dictionary<string, Phrase>();
public class Phrase
{
    public string Role = null;
}
```

My create array and remove the same value code goes here:

```
//Create Array
        List<int> roleIntList = new List<int>();
        foreach(var roles in Phrases){
            var roleNode = roles.Value as Phrase;
            int roleNum = int.Parse(roleNode.Role);
            roleIntList.Add(roleNum);//this can't get value 2,1,1,2,1,2;;
            int [] roleInt = roleIntList.Distinct().ToArray();//this not work;
        }
```

Comment: Your XML has several root elements. Your example code **cannot** work. It must throw an exception in the second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code labeled // Create Array it looks like you may want to move this line:

```
 int [] roleInt = roleIntList.Distinct().ToArray();
```

to be outside the foreach loop:

```
 List<int> roleIntList = new List<int>();
 foreach(var roles in Phrases){
      var roleNode = roles.Value as Phrase;
      int roleNum = int.Parse(roleNode.Role);
      roleIntList.Add(roleNum);//this can't get value 2,1,1,2,1,2;;
 }

 int [] roleInt = roleIntList.Distinct().ToArray();//this not work;
```

Comment: I've run your code.  It doesn't compile, but after you make it compile it outputs `{2, 1}`.  If you're getting that issue then your posted code doesn't match what you're running.  I'd strongly suggest you change the approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're going to use an XML API then LINQ to XML `XDocument` is *far* better to work with than the creaking `XmlDocument` API.

Second, if you're just trying to get the XML into an object model then `XmlSerializer` is what you should be looking at.  You will have very little code to write in comparison to manually parsing this:

```
[XmlRoot("Phrases")]    
public class Phrases : List<Phrase>
{

}

public class Phrase
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Role { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize your XML:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Phrases));

using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var phrasesList = (Phrases)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

And to get your unique roles:

```
var uniqueRoles = phrasesList.Select(p => p.Role).Distinct();
```

I've assumed that your XML has a root node  (your code above would throw an exception as it doesn't).  For the example, I'm using `Phrases`, though if you add more information I can change this.